# Converting integer to String in android fails

Tags: java, android

I want to convert an `int` value to `String` with this method:

```
String.valueof(12);
```

But i get this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'i(java.lang.String)'
```

i tried with this method too:

```
Integer.toString(12);
```

But i still got the same error. Why?

**UPDATE:**
i do this inside Log,i like this:

```
Log.i(String.valueOf(12));
```

Comment: Don't you have to pass two strings to the Log.i function? The first is the tag, the second is the value to be logged

Comment: Use: Log.i("TAG",String.valueOf(12));

Comment: Just a note that `String.valueof(12);` should have a capitol O like: `String.valueOf(12);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you got it, but anyways:

The log functions always require at least two arguments, the first being the TAG and second being the string to be logged.

For more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 2):

there is no method siganture in Log class with i(string) ->http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

I suggest:

```
Log.i("",String.valueOf(12));
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
Log.i("Value",""+12);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `int` to `String` conversion is working fine.

Your issue is that `Log.i()` takes two parameters. One is a tag that you can define like so in your class:

```
final private String TAG = "MyTag";
```

Then pass into `Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(15));`

Answer (score 1):

The invocation of `Log.i` is incorrect. You can read the function details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#i(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Simply try:

```
Log.i("INFO LOG", Integer.toString(12));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 
`String.valueof(12);` is alright

But we can use `Log.i(..)` in two ways

```
 Log.i(tag, msg);

 Log.i(tag, msg, tr);//Throwable tr
```

In your code ,you just have to **add tag** it will run find with out error message.

Hope this will be helpful ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add "" with the number and it will be changed to String

```
String.valueof(12 + "");
```